# why does this if statement in mysql query always return null?

Tags: mysql

Why does the following code, always return `NULL` ?

### **Query**

```
SELECT if(sum(amount)=NULL,0,sum(amount)) as amount
FROM item_details 
WHERE order_id = 1390;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing with NULL in mysql gives NULL. Please use `sum(amount) IS NULL` or `sum(amount) IS NOT NULL` instead.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

Answer (score 4):

Your statement should only return `NULL` when the value is `NULL`.  The condition `sum(amount) = NULL` will always return "unknown", which is treated as "false".  Hence, only the `else` part is returned and the `if` is not really doing anything.

You probably intend `sum(amount) is null`.

As mentioned in another answer, `coalesce()` is a better solution.  The correct form is:

```
select coalesce(sum(amount), 0)
from item_details
where order_id = 1390;
```

If you do this:

```
select sum(coalesce(amount, 0))
from item_details
where order_id = 1390;
```

You will still get `NULL` when there is no match.

Comment: @plalx . . . I also deleted my comment.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

try changing to

sum( coalesce( amount, 0 )) as amount

Comment: That doesn't say why it returns `NULL`, you are just offering an alternative solution to the problem.

Comment: This returns `NULL` too

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT if((sum(amount))=NULL,0,sum(amount)) as amount
FROM item_details 
WHERE order_id = 1390;
```

Comment: How it will be differ from question, both are same

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT if(sum(amount)=NULL,0,sum( coalesce( amount, 0 ))
FROM item_details 
WHERE order_id = 1390;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that the query you're looking for?

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(I.amount),0) as amount
FROM item_details I
WHERE I.order_id = 1390
GROUP BY I.order_id
```

I use `IFNULL` and a `GROUP BY` clause in order to get the expected result.

Hope this will help you

Comment: Downvote? It can be useful to comment this downvote so i can understand my error and learn from that

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is not equals to any value and not equals to `NULL`.

**`NULL` means:** the value is not set -> unknown value. You can not compare `NULL` to anything with normal comparsion operators (=, <, >, etc), it has no value.

`SUM(Amount) = NULL` is always `UNKNOWN`. `UNKONWN` is stated as FALSE in comparsions.

You can handle `NULL` values via its related functions and comparsion operators such as `COALESCE(expr1, expr2, ..., exprN)`, `IS NULL`, etc.

See [MySQL documentation - Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) for more info.

You should change the `if(sum(amount)=NULL,0,sum(amount))` expression to `COALESCE(SUM(amount), 0)` to achive your goal.

[`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html) returns the first not-null expression.